# Memory utilization of ecs services more than 100%

Tags: amazon-ecs

ECS show metrics as the cluster level and at the service level. At the services level the Memory utilization is showing above 100% How is that possible.

The CPU and Memory settings of the tasks in the servics.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its possible if the task definition of service has soft limit defined using `memoryDefinition` parameter instead of hard limit `memory` parameter. Basically it can use memory from cluster if available. See [AWS Service Utilization Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html#service_utilization) for details.